# Display A Random User Profile In Twitter Widget

Tags: javascript, dynamic, twitter, widget, render

I have six twitter user names which I would like to display on my page. Rather than display all six at once, I want to just pick one randomly and show one at a time.

I'm having trouble updating the twitter widget after page load, however. The last line of the widget calls the function setUser() like so:

```
}).render().setUser(document.getElementById("TWITTER_PROFILE_HERE").value).start();
```

How can I change the TWITTER_PROFILE_HERE to the specific name that I've chosen randomly?

Thanks in advance.

FYI here is the link to the create a widget page: http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure to change the var username to whatever you want.

```
<script>

var username = "WHATEVER_USERNAME"; // Add this line in to determine which username you want.

new TWTR.Widget({
  ...
}).render().setUser(username).start();
</script>
```

Or if you want to select one random name from all of your names.

```
<script>

    var usernames = ['user_1', 'user_2', 'user_3', 'user_4'];

    var username = usernames[Math.floor(Math.random()*usernames.length)];    

    new TWTR.Widget({
      ...
    }).render().setUser(username).start();

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, was overthinking things I guess. Basically I load the usernames from an XML file along with a bunch of other data. I was looking for a way to not repeat any code, but since the twitter widget code has to be placed on the page where you want it to show up, I ended up repeating some of the import from XML code. Repeating code irritates me but I guess it'll have to do.